# C++/CLI marshalling/aliasing of memory and struct interoperability

Tags: c, c++-cli, aes

I've wrapped Christophe Devine's [FIPS-197 compliant AES implementation](http://svn.ghostscript.com/ghostscript/tags/ghostscript-9.02/base/aes.h) in a managed C++/CLI class. I'm running into trouble after encrypting/decrypting anywhere from 20 to 52 blocks of 4096 bytes each. I've been able to narrow the issue down to this:

If I declare a native pointer to the `aes_context` struct and just new up the `aes_context` in the constructor, like so

```
Aes::Aes()
    : m_Context(new aes_context)
{
}
```

Then the code will run fine.

But when I attempt to declare the `aes_context` as `array<System::Byte>^` and then in the constructor do this

```
Aes::Aes()
    : m_Context(gcnew array<System::Byte>(sizeof(aes_context)))
{
}
```

While it does compile and in theory should work, this now doesn't

```
pin_ptr<System::Byte> pinned_context = &m_Context[0];
auto context = (aes_context*)pinned_context;
aes_crypt_cbc(context, ...);
```

Effectively and in my limited experience, this should work just fine. The only difference is that the memory was allocated by the GC and that I have to pin the memory before I pass it to the AES library. I should also clarify that this is an error that happens at run-time not a compiler error.

I was unable to reproduce this issue any other way and all tests that I have run against other reference implementation doesn't reveal any issues with implementation. I've even set up two exactly identical test cases, one in C and one in C++/CLI (that uses the managed wrapper to call into the AES library); the managed wrapper doesn't work when backed by a managed *byte array*!?

Since the problem doesn't reveal itself after you've run through a fair deal of data, I've been thinking it's a truncation or alignment issue, but regardless of how much I over-allocate I get the same result.

I'm using the Visual Studio 2012 C++ compiler.

Does anyone know anything that might suggest why this is the case?

Comment: Is that caret in ` array<System::Byte>^` correct/intentional?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah, it tells the C++/CLI compiler that it's a managed type. Any value that is returned by `gcnew` has the type of a `^` to indicate that it's lifetime is managed by the GC. It in turn puts restrictions on how you may use that type to ensure correct behavior.

Comment: OK — I dithered on whether to remove it, and decided to check.  That's a Microsoft extension to the C++11 standard (and/or any earlier C++ standards) isn't it?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson You can examine the source by following the link to the original AES implementation (aes.h) `aes_context` is declared there. `aes_context` in this case is a completely native type, so it shouldn't matter and it's being viewed through a byte array, which in turn is what is being pinned not the *struct*

Comment: @JonathanLeffler No no, it's the syntax for the Microsoft C++/CLI extension, it allows you to mix managed .NET code and native C/C++ in a straightforward manner.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren Yes, just noticed the link so removed the comment until I had a look :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure it's the *only* problem, but `aes_context` is declared to contain a pointer, `rk`;

```
typedef struct
{
    int nr;                     /*!<  number of rounds  */
    unsigned long *rk;          /*!<  AES round keys    */
    unsigned long buf[68];      /*!<  unaligned data    */
}
aes_context;
```

...that is set by (for example) `aes_setkey_enc` to point to an address insinde `buf` inside the same context;

```
ctx->rk = RK = ctx->buf;
```

If - between that pointer set and your pinning the pointer - the context memory block is moved in memory, ctx->rk will point to unallocated memory.

I suspect making `m_Context` a pinned pointer to keep it permanently pinned instead of pinning it temporarily for each call would make the program run successfully.

Comment: Of course, that's it! I changed it so I stored `rk`, relative `buf` and voila. Thanks, I've been stuck with this for quite a while!